# Prove that $f(x, y)=xy$ is continuous on $S^1$ without moving to $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I provided an answer to [Showing that $f(x, y)=xy$ is continuous on $S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903282/showing-that-fx-y-xy-is-continuous-on-s1).

However, it was through a cumbersome proof moving back and forth from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R$.

Is there a way to to provide a proof that would avoid that move to $\mathbb R$?

I.e. using the manifold structure of $S^1$?

Comment: $xy$ as in complex multiplication? Once you know that multiplication is continuous your $f$ is simply a restriction.

Comment: The manifold structure of $\mathbb{S}^1$ can be seen as the embedded submanifold structure of $\mathbb{S}^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$. So the continuity of the product in $\mathbb{C}$ implies the continuity in $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: Thank you guys! How to miss the obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication map $\mu : \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, \mu(z,w) = z \cdot w$, is obviously continuous because
$$\lvert z \cdot w - z_0 \cdot w_0 \rvert = \lvert z \cdot w -  z \cdot w_0 + z \cdot w_0  -z_0 \cdot w_0 \lvert  \le \lvert z \rvert \cdot \lvert w -  w_0 \rvert + \lvert z -  z_0 \rvert \cdot \lvert w_0 \rvert \\ \le (\lvert z_0 \rvert + \lvert z -  z_0 \rvert) \cdot \lvert w -  w_0 \rvert + \lvert z -  z_0 \rvert \cdot \lvert w_0 \rvert \\ = \lvert z_0 \rvert \cdot \lvert w -  w_0 \rvert + \lvert z -  z_0 \rvert \cdot \lvert w_0 \rvert + \lvert z -  z_0 \rvert \cdot \lvert w -  w_0 \rvert .$$

Your map $f$ is the restriction of $\phi$.